# c++ 2d linked list: how can i insert or remove an element?

Tags: c++, linked-list

the code below are my `Node class`, `LinkedList class` and `main()`. 
My problem is when i `insert()` and `delete()` from a `1d LinkedList`, it shows no errors, but when i do this to a `2d LinkList`, the elements doesn't change, could anyone guide me the proper way to create and use a `2d LinkedList`?

```
template<class ItemType>
class Node
{
private:
   ItemType        item; 
   Node<ItemType>* next; 

public:
   Node();
   Node(const ItemType& anItem);
   void setNext(Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr);
   ItemType getItem() const ;
   Node<ItemType>* getNext() const ;
};

template<class ItemType>
Node<ItemType>::Node() : next(nullptr) {}

template<class ItemType>
Node<ItemType>::Node(const ItemType& anItem) : item(anItem), next(nullptr) {}

template<class ItemType>
void Node<ItemType>::setNext(Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr)
{
   next = nextNodePtr;
}

template<class ItemType>
ItemType Node<ItemType>::getItem() const
{
   return item;
}

template<class ItemType>
Node<ItemType>* Node<ItemType>::getNext() const
{
   return next;
}
```

LinkedList

```
template<class ItemType>
class LinkedList 
{
private:
    Node<ItemType>* headPtr;                            
    int itemCount;               
    Node<ItemType>* getNodeAt(int pos) const;    
public:
    LinkedList();   
    void delete(int pos);    
    void insert(const ItemType& newEntry);
    ItemType getElement(int pos) const;
    ItemType operator [] (int index) const;
};

template<class ItemType>
void LinkedList<ItemType>::delete(int pos)
{
        Node<ItemType>* curPtr = nullptr;
        if (position == 1)
        {
            curPtr = headPtr; 
            headPtr = headPtr->getNext();
        }
        else
        {
            Node<ItemType>* prevPtr = getNodeAt(pos - 1);
            curPtr = prevPtr->getNext();
            prevPtr->setNext(curPtr->getNext());
        }  
        curPtr->setNext(nullptr);
        delete curPtr;
        curPtr = nullptr;

        itemCount--;  
} 

template<class ItemType>
void LinkedList<ItemType>::insert(const ItemType& newEntry)
{
    Node<ItemType>* curPtr = new Node<ItemType> (newEntry);
    if (getLength() == 0)
    {
        headPtr = curPtr;
    }
    else
    {
        Node<ItemType>* prevPtr = getNodeAt(getLength());
        prevPtr->setNext(curPtr);
    }
    itemCount++;
}

template<class ItemType>
Node<ItemType>* LinkedList<ItemType>::getNodeAt(int pos) const
{
   Node<ItemType>* curPtr = headPtr;
   for (int skip = 1; skip < pos; skip++)
      curPtr = curPtr->getNext();

   return curPtr;
}  

template<class ItemType>
ItemType LinkedList<ItemType>::getElement(int pos) const 
{
      Node<ItemType>* nodePtr = getNodeAt(pos);
      return nodePtr->getItem();
}
```

main

```
    LinkedList <int> s;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        s.insert(i);
    }

    LinkedList <int> t;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        t.insert(2*i + 100);
    }

    LinkedList <LinkedList <int> > ss;
    ss.insert(s);
    ss.insert(t);
    ss[1].insert(1119);
    ss[1].delete(1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        cout << ss[1].getElement(i) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        cout << ss[2].getElement(i) << " " ;
    }
```

the outcome remains unchanged:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
102 104 106 108 110 112 114 116 118 120
```

expected outcome:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1119
102 104 106 108 110 112 114 116 118 120
```

Comment: Doesn't compile. You haven't included the definition of `operator[]` which is very relevant to your question, because if it returns a copy which I suspect, rather than a reference then you will get the behaviour you describe. Naming a member function `delete` is a bad idea.

Comment: @acraig5075 sorry, i missed out the definition, here is it `template<class ItemType>
ItemType LinkedList<ItemType>::operator [] (int index) const
{
    return getElement(index);
}` . And I'm going to change the name of the `delete` function

Comment: Don't post updates in comments, [edit] your question.

Comment: Your linked list manages its own memory but has no user-defined destructor, nor copy constructir or assignment operator. This is a recipe for a disaster. Please look up "rule of three" and "rule of five".